# When viewing entries in CP, can I view custom fields?

Tags: control-panel, custom-fields, ee3

I'd like to show custom fields--more than just defaults (ID/Title/Date/Status). Anyone know of a way to do this? Using EE 3.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use Zenbu. really nice addon suite https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zenbu